# Assigning workflows on folders

Tags: interaction-design, copywriting, workflow, microinteractions

I'm working on a rewrite of our Workflow feature. Workflows are optional, and you can apply workflows only on folders. Folders start with no workflows assigned to them. A folder can be a part of only one workflow. All current subfolders inherit applied workflow when you apply a workflow to a folder. You can also change or turn off workflows according to your needs. When you create a new subfolder you have to define the workflow.

There are 3 different states:

- no workflow
- choose workflow
- Use (inherit) workflow from the parent folder

The user assigns workflow like this:

1. You usually start with No Workflow
2. then you Choose Workflow
3. **if** you create a subfolder you assign the "Use Workflow from the parent..." option

The logic behind this is

- no
- yes -> option 1 (choose workflow); option 2 (inherit workflow)

In the past, we used radio buttons and all options were always available, even the "Use Workflow from the parent..." one had nothing to inherit (the parent folder had no workflow assigned):
[image: Old interface for assigning workflows]
In the past, you also couldn't see which Workflow is assigned to which folder. You could check if you check by going to this process (assigning Workflow) and clicked cancel... Now, this is visible at any time.

My proposed solution:

- I changed the language from Use -> Inherit; and Set -> Assign.
- I would disable the inherit option if it's currently not possible
- I'm tempted to move the "chose workflow" to the bottom because the Description part is variable (for each workflow) and it can get really long.
  [image: OPTION 1: Choose workflow is in the second place and it needs to expand]
  OPTION 1: Choose workflow is in the second place and it needs to expand

But I'm not sure if this order is the right one or even if we need to have the "inherit option" as a separate one.
[image: OPTION 2: Choose workflow is on the bottom; OPTION 3: Choose and Inherit are merged]
OPTION 2: Choose workflow is on the bottom; OPTION 3: Choose and Inherit are merged

My questions:

1. Is language improved?
2. Should the "Assign workflow" be at the bottom so the Description can expand freely
3. Should I just merge Choose and Inherit options?

Thank you!